# The order of the js scripts matters?

Tags: javascript, drupal-8

Introductory note: In Drupal 8 we place our our custom javaScript code on a file called: main.js

Initially I placed in that file the following scrip (that generates a Tab on the front page of the site), and it worked perfectly:

```
function openPage(pageName,elmnt,color) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("js--bottons-ecards");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}
document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

Latter I added to the same file another script to generate a button over a video on another page of the site:

```
var videoPlayButton,
videoWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('video-wrapper')[0],
video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0],
videoMethods = {
    renderVideoPlayButton: function() {
        if (videoWrapper.contains(video)) {
            this.formatVideoPlayButton()
            video.classList.add('has-media-controls-hidden')
            videoPlayButton = document.getElementsByClassName('video-overlay-play-button')[0]
            videoPlayButton.addEventListener('click', this.hideVideoPlayButton)
        }
    },
    formatVideoPlayButton: function() {
        videoWrapper.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '\
            <svg class="video-overlay-play-button" viewBox="0 0 200 200" alt="Play video">\
                <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="90" fill="none" stroke-width="15" stroke="#fff"/>\
                <polygon points="70, 55 70, 145 145, 100" fill="#fff"/>\
            </svg>\
        ')
    },
    hideVideoPlayButton: function() {
        video.play()
        videoPlayButton.classList.add('is-hidden')
        video.classList.remove('has-media-controls-hidden')
        video.setAttribute('controls', 'controls')
    }
}
videoMethods.renderVideoPlayButton();
```

Unfortunately seems that only one of the scripts works on that file. The script placed in second place on the file "main.js", doesn't work. Is there a way to make the two scripts run in the same file or do I need to create a ".js" file for each script I want to add to my theme?

Obviously In new to drupal and javascript two...

I Appreciate some help to get in the rational of js.

Comment: If scriptA.js calls a function in scriptB.js while it's loading, it has to be loaded after it so that the function will be available. There can be other dependencies like this.

Comment: So when we add different scripts the order that they are placed in the main.js file is crucial to make all of them work?

Comment: Only if they have dependencies between them. E.g. bootstrap depends on jQuery, so you have to load jQuery first.

Comment: If these are the actual scripts used on the site then I don't see how scriptA calls scriptB.

Comment: Yes these are the actual scripts and thats why, in my ignorance, I'm surprised that their order was relevant. But in fact it is!!! I just wonder why...